# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString after change asp.net identity key on onion architect

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-2.1

I use asp.net core 2.1 and identity in project that use onion architect

when i want to add-migration i get error that say:

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString

[image]

```
namespace CafeTahlil.Data.Context
{
    public class CafeTahlilDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<long>, IdentityRole<long>, long>
    {
        public CafeTahlilDbContext()
        {

        }
        public CafeTahlilDbContext(DbContextOptions<CafeTahlilDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            IConfigurationRoot config = builder.Build();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("CafeTahlilDbContext"));
        }
    }
}
```

and my Startup.cs file is:

```
namespace CafeTahlil.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<CafeTahlilDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CafeTahlilDbContext"))
            );
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser<Guid>>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CafeTahlilDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

the connection string is in appsetting.json file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CafeTahlilDbContext": "Server=.;Database=db_CafeTahlil;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

cane anyone help me 
this problem is after identity customization

Comment: In your appsetting.json you have a misspelling word ConnectionStrings with 3 n.

Comment: thank u but its not solution